# Typo3 8.7 Indexed Search: exclude images

Tags: typo3-8.x, tx-indexed-search

I am looking for the proper way to exclude images from being indexed. I tried using `plugin.tx_indexedsearch.settings.mediaList = 0` *(I deduced that number from the mediaTypes select list in the advanced search form)* but that only changed the options in the MediaTypes select list.

I found out that one of the hidden fields is `tx_indexedsearch_pi2[search][mediaType]` and that there is a default setting `searchParams.mediaType = -1` in the extbase variable dump. So I tried `plugin.tx_indexedsearch.searchParams.mediaType = 0` in the TypoScript settings – but to no effect.

So what I did was to change the value of the above mentioned hidden field in the template file `Partials/Form.html` from `{searchParams.mediaType}` to `0`. But I reckon that will only keep files from being displayed in the results not from being indexed in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my configuration the following TS helped:

```
plugin.tx_indexedsearch.settings.mediaList =
```

and I excluded in the extension configuration (basic.ignoreExtensions)

```
jpg, png, gif, jpeg
```

Comment: Thank you, Robert! But unfortunately that doesn’t change a thing for me. I tried several times with deleting the caches and clearing the index tables in between.

Comment: @clivebeckett    I extended my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I seem not even to need the plugin.tx_indexedsearch.settings.mediaList